# I tying to get access to this ID from an object in react

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object

[image]

Trying to access id from this object in react js but not able to access it can anyone tell how can i do that?

```
const[MovieList,setMovieList] = useState([]);
```

the list is stored in MovieList.

Comment: What have you tried? Doesn't `MovieList[0].id` work?

Comment: Thanks this kind of works but when i try to add this in second api call it says cannot read property of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that, it is an array that has the object in every element of that arr.

[  {..}  ,  {...}  ,  {...}   ]

so, you can access the id of the object present in an array :

// let the response is stored in "response" variable

const response = [   {...}  , {...} ,{...}   ]

const {id} = response[0]